# Normalizar array de objetos y crear una key nueva

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, javascript-objeto

Estoy consumiendo una API y debo transformar `arrToNormalize` y ordenarlos por `categoryId` pero para cada una debo mostrar un `String` en vez del número de id. La idea es que para el caso 1 muestre `Mantenimiento`, para el caso 2 `Revisión`, pero como hay N casos o id's debería crear una función donde yo lo haga en cada caso que valor recibe cada id (pienso en un `switch`).

`normalizedArr` es lo que yo quiero mostrar:

```
let arrToNormalize = 
[
    {serviceId: 0, categoryId: 1, name: 20.000km},
    {serviceId: 1, categoryId: 1, name: 30.000km},
    {serviceId: 2, categoryId: 1, name: 40.000km},
    {serviceId: 3, categoryId: 2, name: Filtro},
    {serviceId: 4, categoryId: 2, name: Aceite},
    {serviceId: 5, categoryId: 2, name: Chapa},
]

let normalizedArr = 
[
    {
        categoryId: Mantenimiento,
        services:
        [
            {
                serviceId: 0,
                name: 20.000km
            },
            {
                serviceId: 1,
                name: 30.000km
            },
            {
                serviceId: 2,
                name: 40.000km
            },
        ]
    }
    {
        categoryId: Revisión,
        services:
        [
            {
                serviceId: 3,
                name: Filtro
            },
            {
                serviceId: 4,
                name: Aceite
            },
            {
                serviceId: 5,
                name: Chapa
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiza un **array.map**  resuelva tu problema, intente lo siguiente no se si sea la opcion mas optima pero es una solucion.

```js
let arrToNormalize = [
  {serviceId: 0, categoryId: 1, name: '20.000km'},
  {serviceId: 1, categoryId: 1, name: '30.000km'},
  {serviceId: 2, categoryId: 1, name: '40.000km'},
  {serviceId: 3, categoryId: 2, name: 'Filtro'},
  {serviceId: 4, categoryId: 2, name: 'Aceite'},
  {serviceId: 5, categoryId: 2, name:' Chapa'}
  ]
  
  let categories = [
    {
        categoryId: 'Mantenimiento',
      services: []
    },
    {
        categoryId: 'Revisión',
      services: []
    }
  ];
  arrToNormalize.map((item) => {
    if (item.categoryId === 1) {
        categories[0].services.push({ serviceId: item.serviceId, name: item.name})
    } else if (item.categoryId === 2)  {
        categories[1].services.push({ serviceId: item.serviceId, name: item.name})
    }
  }  )
  console.log(categories)
```

Saludos